Casting to a Member Type in Scala
I'm using the Apache POI library 5.2.3 in Scala to create a line chart in a PowerPoint presentation.
// createData returns XDDFChartData
var chartData = chart.createData(
    ChartTypes.LINE,
    bottomAxis,
    leftAxis
).asInstanceOf[XDDFLineChartData]

// addSeries returns XDDFChartData.Series
var series = chartData.addSeries(bottomAxisDataSource, seriesDataSource)
series.setSmooth(false)


error: value setSmooth is not a member of org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartData.Series

However I need series to be of type  XDDFLineChartData.Series not XDDFChartData.Series so I can access the setSmooth() method. How do I cast to the inner member type Series here?
The following attempt fails
chartData.addSeries(bottomAxisDataSource, seriesDataSource).asInstanceOf[XDDFLineChartData.Series]

with

error: type Series is not a member of object org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFLineChartData


Try XDDFLineChartData#Series

@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez wow, as simple as that. That works - please put this as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution
